# How to use a php variable inside script tags?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, routes, axios

I have this logic in my app for changing the quantity of an item in a shopping cart:

```
<script>
const options = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')

Array.from(options).forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('change', function() {
        const id = element.getAttribute('data-id')

        axios.patch(`{{ Route::currentRouteName(), ${id} }}`, {
            quantity: this.value
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            window.location.href = '{{ route('cartIndex', App::getLocale()) }}'
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            window.location.href = '{{ route('cartIndex', App::getLocale()) }}'
        });
        })
});
</script>
```

The line

```
 axios.patch(`{{ Route::currentRouteName(), ${id} }}`, {
            quantity: this.value
        })
```

used to be like this:

```
 axios.patch(`/cart/${id}`, {
            quantity: this.value
        })
```

I made a localization functionality. Now I need to pass a `{lang}` parameter to every route so that's why I'm using `{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}`. however, the rest of the URL is stored in a javascript variable.

What's the best way to get the value of the `id` javascript variable and pass it to the `Route::currentRouteName()` PHP method?

Comment: You should not include inline scripts in PHP file. Instead, store the scripts in their own file, and use `src` attribute to link the script to the page. Please make a search how to pass variables in that case, this is asked multiple times per day.

Comment: _"What's the best way to get the value of the id javascript variable and pass it to the Route::currentRouteName() PHP method?"_ - none, because without making a new request to the server first, that is of course impossible. Explanation, see duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest in stead of using route, you can use url.You can use this by following :

```
let lang = "{{ $lang }}";

let url = "{{'Route::currentRouteName()'}}" + '/' + lang;
```

Or

```
let lang = @json($lang);

let url = @json('/cart/' . $lang);
```